# Sound Settings window too wide

Tags: pulseaudio, window-management, gnome-control-center

[image: Very very wide system sound settings window.]

In the picture you can see that the sound settings window is absurdly wide. There is one sound output device that plays to all connected devices, and it's name is very long, as it lists all of the devices. This being so long has pushed the borders of my window past the edges of the screen, and now spans multiple desktops.

Being able to do any of the following should fix my problem.

A. Force the window dimensions to remain within the screen.
B. Wrap the long line.
C. Give the device a custom shorter name.
D. Make the window resizeable, with the device list horizontally-scrollable.

Comment: I think this is clearly a bug in `gnome-control-center`. You can report it on launchpad...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the window size of the GNOME sound settings is hard-coded and can not be changed. It will adapt its size according to the length of display for a chosen audio sink.

To overcome this we can use a custom name (`device.description`) for the rather lengthy **combined sink** to not list all slaves we had used.

Rather than by running **paprefs** we create this custom named combined sink by loading `module-combine-sink` (or `module-combine` in pulseaudio < 1.0) from a terminal (or from our `default.pa` in case we always need such a combined sink) with the following parameters:

```
pactl load-module module-combine-sink sink_properties=device.description=Combined
```

After that the combined sink name will nicely fit into the sound settings window:

[image]